# Return Value for Parent function from sub function

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I have a form submit event handler and within that I have a `.each` function that I would like to return false for its parent(form.submit) to prevent the form from submitting.  I can't figure out how to do it.

```
$("#form").submit(function () {
$(selector).each (function () { if ($(this).val() === ""}) {return false;});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the state in a variable and return that after the `.each()`

```
$("#form").submit(function () {
    var correctForm = true;
    $(selector).each(function () {
        if (this.value === '') correctForm = false;
    });
    return correctForm;
});
```

Also you can use the `.value` property of input elements instead of creating jquery objects and using the `.val()`

Comment: Would there be a benefit to use .value over .val()?  Such as speed?

Comment: Yes, since you already have a reference to the DOM and `value` is a property of that element it is faster to access it directly than calling two functions (*one to the `$(this)` to create the jQuery object and then the `.val()` to get is value*)

Answer (score 1):

Try using preventDefault on the original event object

```
$("#form").submit(function (event) {
    $(selector).each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === ""){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a value directly from a inner function, instead you can use a variable to do it like

```
$("#form").submit(function () {
    var valid = true;
    $(selector).each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return valid ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $("#form").submit(function () {
 $(selector).each (function () { if ($(this).val() === ""){}
        return false;
 });
 });
```